# Any undesirable effects in running ScheduledExecutorService.scheduleAtFixedRate with long delay?

Tags: java, threadpool, java-threads

Can there be any issue in scheduling a thread as follows?

```
private ScheduledExecutorService dataPublishingExecutorService = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();

dataPublishingExecutorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(() -> {
                this.publish(this.topic, this.sessionId);
            }, 0L, Long.MAX_VALUE , TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

My client code calls a method that has this logic, and I am trying to avoid the thread being repeatedly running. Therefore I am trying to set a delay to the max level possible through my client code. Just trying to understand whether there can be any undesirable effect due to this?

Comment: I'm trying to understand the *desirable* effect you think you're getting with that code. You're scheduling something, but putting a delay so long that scheduling is obviously not your goal. So what on earth are you doing? Perhaps you're confused about threading?

Comment: The dependant code needs to have support to not schedule threads. Until the fix is done, I am trying to avoid the task being repeated by passing in a long value to this method.

Comment: So you want it to run only once now (per deploy), and in the future something will be fixed and it will run more often? If that's the case, then yes putting a long enough delay will give you that functionality. IIRC it uses a `DelayQueue` to get the task, so it doesn't matter how long the delay is.

Comment: Yes, it is a temporary fix, but needed to understand any issues of doing this.